# Typeorm cannot connect to Postgres

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am using Typeorm to connect to the database, but it cannot connect and shows no errors.
If I comment the line where the connection is established all works fine.

This is my code

index.ts

```js
import {App} from './app';
import { createConnection,Connection } from "typeorm";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import config  from './ormconfig';

async function main() {    
    dotenv.config();   
    try{
        await createConnection(config);
       
        console.log('Connected to the database');
    }catch(error){
        console.log(`Error connecting to the database\n ${error}`.red);
    }
    const app = new App([
        // new GrandTotalController()
        // new AuthenticationController,
                        // new UserController(),
        //                 new AccountMonthController
                    ],
        5000);
    await app.listen();
}
main();
```

ormconfing.ts

```js
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  port: Number(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
  entities: [
    __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
  ],
  migrations: [
    'src/migrations/*.ts',
  ],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
};
export = config;
```

my terminal :
[image: output terminal]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the only way I found to solve this was to create a new project using the command:

```
typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres
```

and adapt my project to this structure